# How to close JQuery dialog from within a loaded jsp page

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML (home.html) page that loads a dialog like this:

```
<body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function call_popup() {
            var myDialog = $('#modalbox')
                .load('popup.jsp' )
                .dialog({
                    modal: 'true',
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'page title',
                    width: 850,
                    height: 750,
                    resizable: 'false',
                    close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
                    open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", $(this).parent()).hide(); }
                });

                myDialog.dialog('open');
                return false;

       }
      </script>
      <input type="button" onclick="call_popup()" value="Give me a dialog" />
<div  id='modalbox'></div>
</body>
```

In popup.jsp I have a button and a handler:

```
<input type="button" id="closeButton" value="Close" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#closeButton').click(function () {

            return false; 
    });
});
```

What code within the button handler will close the dialog?

Comment: Looks like you call your popup box #modalbox. You could remove it from the DOM with $('#modalbox').remove(); or $('#modalbox').dialog('close');

Answer (score 2):

1. in the pop up JSP page give the div id same as that of the one (div id for modal window) in main JSP page
2. on click function of the close button in the popup JSP  close the dialog giving the div id

   ```
   $('#closeButton').click(function() {

       $("#modalbox'").dialog('close');

   });
   ```

It works :)